# Determine if the dial pad tones are set

Tags: android, audio

In **settings/sound/advanced** (on my Pixel) you can specify to have dial pad tones `on` or `off`.

Is there a way of getting this value within an app? I'm not interested in changing it, just reading the value.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a strange day and it seems I've already coded this up. In case anyone else has the same question, here is my code...

```
 boolean isDtmfToneEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                                    Settings.System.DTMF_TONE_WHEN_DIALING, 1) != 0;
```